# Is it possible to disable "Double-tap for period" in an Android EditText?

Tags: android, android-edittext

It's been messing up my Edit Text filter. When I double-tap space, the previous character is deleted instead. Here is my filter:

```
@Override
    public CharSequence filter(CharSequence source, int start, int end, Spanned dest, int dstart, int dend) {
        if (!isValid(source)) { // This simple calls Matcher.matches
            return "";
        }

        return null;
    }
```

When I double tap the space key, the filter is called three times with the following sources:

1. Source with a space source (" ")
2. An empty source ("") (similar to a backspace) --> This one deletes the last character
3. A ". " source

I tried just retaining the last character instead:

```
if(source.toString().isEmpty()) {
            return ((Character) dest.toString().charAt(dest.toString().length()-1)).toString();
        }
```

It fixed the issue but I can't do backspace anymore because of that workaround. Is there a way to just disable the "double-tap space for period" functionality just for this single EditText? I noticed the address bar in the Google Chrome app seems to disable this functionality and just treats double-tapped space as two spaces.

Answer (score 3):

In my case, my input is just a one-line field. I simply set the inputType to textVisiblePassword:

```
android:inputType="textVisiblePassword"
```

This also handles my specification to disable suggestions/dictionary. However, I'd like to see if there are other ways to do this since other people may need suggestions/dictionary and just want to disable the double-tap for period functionality. Additional answers are welcome.

Answer (score 0):

Major hackage, but this works if you don't allow spaces or periods in your text in your input filter :-)

```
        private char prevLastChar;

    @Override
    public CharSequence filter(CharSequence source, int start, int end,
                               Spanned dest, int dstart, int dend) {

        boolean isAutoPeriod = StringUtils.eq(source.toString(), ". ");
        if (!isAutoPeriod && (dstart == dend) && (dend == dest.length()) && (dest.length() > 0)) {
            prevLastChar = dest.charAt(dest.length()-1);
        }
        if (isAutoPeriod && (dstart == dend) && (dend == dest.length())) {
            if (source instanceof SpannableStringBuilder) {
                return SpannableStringBuilder.valueOf(Character.toString(prevLastChar));
            } else {
                return Character.toString(prevLastChar);
            }
        }
```

Then add whatever you want for the rest of the input filter.

We really should have an inputType that disables autoPunctuation :-(